# Visualforce - Lookup InputField not Displaying picklist when in Dynamic Component

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

Standard Salesforce OOB lookups display a picklist field when a value is entered that matches multiple records (In my scenario a lookup to the 'country' table could return Australia & Austria for the value "Au").

I am finding that in a basic visualforce page this is working as expected. For example I enter 'au' into a lookup to the country table, then click a custom 'Save' button (which returns a null page ref): 
[image: lookup flied]

Then the expected picklist field is rendered upon refresh of the page: 
[image: picklist]

But when I have a similar field created from a dynamic component (on a separate page) the picklist is no longer rendered upon refresh of the page: 
[image]
The picklist doesn't appear: 
[image]

I have tried stripping out all JS functions from the save button on this page and just returning a null page ref. But still no picklist.

Question: Does someone know how I can get the picklist to show for this field within a dynamic component?

Comment: Can you share your code snippet?

Comment: I am working at recreating this in another environment then will amend the question.